# Property or method “subscribed” is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.in Vue.js

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5

in my vue subscribe-button components, i have mentioned every part props computed and methods. In computed i mentioned the subscribed property: but still it's giving me an error of:-

" [Vue warn]: Property or method "subscribed" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties. "

Subscribe-buttom.js

```
Vue.component('subscribe-button', {
props: {
    profile: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
        default: () => ({})
    },
    subscriptions: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        default: () => []
    }
},
computed: {
    subscribed: function() {
        if (!__auth() || this.profile.user_id == __auth().id) return false
        return !!this.subscriptions.find(subscription => subscription.user_id == __auth().id)
    }
},
methods: {

    toggleSubscription() {
        if (!__auth()) {
            alert('Please login to Subscribe')
        }
    }
}

 })
```

This is a part of my show.blade.php

```
<div class="text-center">
    <subscribe-button :profile="{{ $profile }}" :subscriptions="{{ $profile->subscriptions }}" inline-template>
     <button @click='toggleSubscription' class="btn btn-danger">
      @{{ subscribed ? 'Unsubscribe' : 'Subscribe' }} 7k
     </button>
    </subscribe-button>
  </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvvIQ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIYEY.png)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674546/property-or-method-subscribed-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-du

Answer (score 1):

Counter intuitive but try just doing this and see if it will solve your problem. Add a mounted hook and add this

```
mounted() {
    const test = this.subscribed;
}
```

Or maybe this link can help light the path https://forum.vuejs.org/t/unable-to-use-computed-property-in-component-template/69775

Comment: in subscribe-button.js ?

Comment: @RashmiRanjanSahoo ah yes, sorry for not being clear